# pybind11 compiling error in common.h(635): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition

Tags: unreal-engine4, pybind11

I am trying to use pybind11 in UnrealeEngine, as a plugin. While I can compile fine a standalone project on Win10 with VS2019 and Python 3.9.0, when compiling inside a UE4 Project I got this error(s):

`D:\work_in_progress\UE4\PB11_TEST\Plugins\myPlugin\Source\PyBind11\include\pybind11\detail/common.h(635): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition`

`D:\work_in_progress\UE4\PB11_TEST\Plugins\myPlugin\Source\PyBind11\include\pybind11\detail/common.h(637): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'pybind11::detail::is_template_base_of_impl<Base>' being compiled`

`D:\work_in_progress\UE4\PB11_TEST\Plugins\myPlugin\Source\PyBind11\include\pybind11\detail/common.h(635): error C2059: syntax error: '<end Parse>'`

...and more...

it is clearly something related to UE4, I already have spent one day trying to figure out where to search, with no result. Could someone maybe point me in the right direction? This happens even if I only #include "pybind11/pybind11.h"`.

Using Visual Studio 2019 14.28.29334 toolchain and Windows 10.0.17763.0 SDK

Thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 1):

With the help of pybind11 crew, I have a found a solution. The issue is caused by a UE4 macro: **check**. To overcome macro pollution in my pybind11 plugin, I added the following code to my header file:

```
THIRD_PARTY_INCLUDES_START
#pragma push_macro("check")
#undef check
#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning (disable : 4191)
#pragma warning (disable : 4686)
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"
#pragma warning (pop)
#pragma pop_macro("check")
THIRD_PARTY_INCLUDES_END
```

As you can see, also a couple of warnings have been silenced, because UE4 enables them (by default in VS2019, they are disabled).

Hope this can be of some help if someone got trapped with the same problem.